# Como fazer a seleção de métodos em uma função e adicionar resultados em uma lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando com uma função deste tipo, que está na minha `main`:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_experiment(outros_parametros,['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA'])
```

Fazer com que apenas alguns métodos sejam selecionados, calculados e os resultados adicionados em uma lista que tem nome de `medidas_importances` desta forma:

```
def run_experiment(FEATURE_METHODS... outros parâmetros):

    for j in FEATURE_METHODS:

        for add in medidas_importances:

            #Faz a seleção dos métodos e adiciona na lista:
            if FEATURE_METHODS == "LA":
                ranks1 = frk.ranks_Lasso(x_train, y_train, features_train, LASSO_CV_K, RESULT_PATH)
                medidas_importances.append(add)

            elif FEATURE_METHODS == "RF":
                ranks2 = frk.ranks_RF(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
                medidas_importances.append(add)

            elif FEATURE_METHODS == "DT":
                ranks3 = frk.ranks_DT(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
                medidas_importances.append(add)

            elif  FEATURE_METHODS == "PCA":
                ranks4 = frk.ranks_PCA(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
                medidas_importances.append(add)

            elif FEATURE_METHODS == "ARD":
                ranks5 = frk.ranks_ARD(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
                medidas_importances.append(add)

            else:
                print("not found")

    print("Imprime importancias")
    print(medidas_importances)

    frk.plot_ranks(FEATURE_METHODS, features_train, 'Cumulative Ranks', RESULT_PATH)
```

Contudo, o cálculo que deveria ser realizado a partir da seleção dos métodos na função `run_experiment` com `['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA']` não retorna nada na lista que foi criada no segundo *loop* `for`.

O que eu posso fazer para que isso funcione?

Comment: Não está claro de onde veio a lista medidas_importances, mas parece que está iterando e adicionando elementos à mesma lista. Veja em https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html:

Code that modifies a collection while iterating over that same collection can be tricky to get right. Instead, it is usually more straight-forward to loop over a copy of the collection or to create a new collection

Se possível, detalhe melhor o que tem em medidas_importances quando o segundo for é iniciado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você faz `for j in FEATURE_METHODS`, então vou assumir que `FEATURE_METHODS` é uma lista (*ou qualquer outro objeto iterável*) contendo os valores "LA", "RF", etc. E dentro do *loop* você faz:

```
if FEATURE_METHODS == "LA":
```

Ou seja, você está comparando a string `"LA"` com a lista. Por isso não entra em nenhum desses `if`'s. Provavelmente o que você quer é comparar o valor de cada elemento, ou seja:

```
if j == "LA":
```

---

Mas além disso, tem outro problema. Você faz um *loop* em `medidas_importances`, e dentro desse *loop* você adiciona elementos a essa mesma lista. Isso é um problema, pois veja o que acontece com esse exemplo simples e aparentemente "inocente":

```
# ATENÇÃO: esse código entra em loop infinito 
lista = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
for i, s in enumerate(lista):
    print(f'verificando posição {i}, valor {s}')
    if s == 'a':
        print(f'inserindo {s} na lista')
        lista.append(s)
```

Esse código entra em *loop* infinito ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/NUpI5y)). A saída é:

```
verificando posição 0, valor a
inserindo a na lista
verificando posição 1, valor b
verificando posição 2, valor c
verificando posição 3, valor a
inserindo a na lista
verificando posição 4, valor a
inserindo a na lista
verificando posição 5, valor a
inserindo a na lista
verificando posição 6, valor a
inserindo a na lista
verificando posição 7, valor a
inserindo a na lista
....
```

Ou seja, conforme ele itera pela lista, elementos vão sendo adicionados no final, e por isso o *loop* nunca termina, pois sempre haverá um novo elemento no fim (e depois de iterar por esse elemento, um novo é adicionado, e por aí vai...)

E é exatamente isso que você está fazendo. Em uma versão simplificada do seu código:

```
medidas_importances = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
FEATURE_METHODS = ['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA']
for j in FEATURE_METHODS:
    for add in medidas_importances:
        if j == 'LA':
            # faz algum cálculo
            print('cálculo para LA')
            medidas_importances.append(add)
        else:
            print('not found')
```

Ao entrar no `for add in medidas_importances`, ele entra no `if j == 'LA'` e adiciona o elemento `add` no final da lista. E por isso o *loop* não termina, e ele acaba caindo no `if` de novo (pois ainda estamos na primeira iteração do `for j`), e adiciona o elemento de novo, e de novo, e de novo... Por isso o código acima imprime "cálculo para LA" indefinidamente, [veja](https://ideone.com/c4Q5SM).

---

Não ficou claro porque você precisa adicionar novamente o mesmo elemento na lista. De qualquer forma, a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) diz que, em vez de modificar uma lista enquanto itera nela, o ideal é criar outra lista para isso, ou iterar sobre uma cópia.

Mas para este caso, também podemos criar uma outra lista para guardar as medidas que foram calculadas:

```
medidas_importances = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
FEATURE_METHODS = ['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA']
calculadas = []
for j in FEATURE_METHODS:
    for add in medidas_importances:
        if j == 'LA':
            # faz algum cálculo
            calculadas.append(add) # adiciona na lista de medidas calculadas, sem alterar a original
        elif j == "RF":
            # faz outro cálculo
            calculadas.append(add)
        elif j == "DT":
           # etc ...
        else:
            print('not found')

# No final, se quiser mesmo adicionar na lista original
medidas_importances.extend(calculadas)
```

Ou seja, crio outra lista para adicionar as medidas, e só no final eu uso `extend` para adicionar os elementos desta lista em `medidas_importances`. Ainda sim, me parece estranho adicionar os mesmos elementos novamente na mesma lista, mas enfim...

---

**Mas**, se você só quer adicionar os resultados dos cálculos na lista, aí não precisa desse segundo `for`:

```
FEATURE_METHODS = ['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA']
medidas_importances = []
for j in FEATURE_METHODS:
    if j == 'LA':
        ranks1 = ...
        medidas_importances.append(ranks1)
    elif j == "RF":
        ranks2 = ...
        medidas_importances.append(ranks2)
    elif j == "DT":
        etc...
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Se bem que tem um pouco de repetição que dá para simplificar. Com exceção do "LA", todas as outras chamadas recebem os mesmos parâmetros, só mudando o nome da função, então poderia ser assim também:

```
medidas_importances = []
funcoes = {
    'LA': frk.ranks_Lasso,
    'RF': frk.ranks_RF,
    'DT': frk.ranks_DT,
    'PCA': frk.ranks_PCA,
    'ARD': frk.ranks_ARD,
}
for j in FEATURE_METHODS:
    if j in funcoes:
        if j == 'LA':
            params = (x_train, y_train, features_train, LASSO_CV_K, RESULT_PATH)
        else:
            params = (x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
        ranks = funcoes[j](*params)
        medidas_importances.append(ranks)
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia criar um dicionário associando os seus Identificadores com as funções correspondentes para evitar o bloco `if/elif/else`. Veja só:

```
# Dicionario associando o identificador
# com a método/funcao correspondente
mapa = {
    'LA'  : frk.ranks_Lasso
    'RF'  : frk.ranks_RF
    'DT'  : frk.ranks_DT
    'ARD' : frk.ranks_ARD
    'PCA' : frk.ranks_PCA
}

def run_experiment(FEATURE_METHODS):
    for m in FEATURE_METHODS:
        try:
            func = mapa[m]
        except KeyError:
            print("Identificador nao encontrado: {}".format(m))

        ranks = func(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_experiment(['LA', 'RF', 'DT', 'ARD', 'PCA'])
```